# Variable in sed parsing

Tags: json, bash, sed

I have a question about json and parsing with sed:

Here is what I get in json:

```
response='{"found":"true","downloadLink":"http:\/\/www.addic7ed.com\/updated\/1\/86593\/2"}'
```

If I use this:

```
downloadLink=`echo $response | sed -e 's/^.*"downloadLink"[ ]*:[ ]*"//' -e 's/".*//'`
```

then `downloadLink` will contain `http:\/\/www.addic7ed.com\/updated\/1\/86593\/2`.

I tried to put a variable instead of downloadLink:

```
downloadLink=`echo $response | sed -e 's/^.*"$value"[ ]*:[ ]*"//' -e 's/".*//'`
```

But it doesn't seem to work properly. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: What output are you trying to get from sed ?

Comment: I'm not sure how any of your assignments are working; in bash, you cannot have a space between the variable name and the `=`.

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited my copy/paste by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes are not expanded in bash. Use double quotes and escape those already used: - like this:

```
echo $response | sed -e "s/^.*\"$value\"[ ]*:[ ]*\"//" -e 's/".*//'
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using two `sed` commands, you can capture the value you are interested like this:

```
echo "$response" | sed -e "s/^.*\"$value\"\s*:\s*\"\([^\"]*\)\".*$/\1/"
```

The contents of the `\( \)` are captured into the variable `\1`. I have chosen to capture `[^\"]*` (any number of characters that are not a double quote), which works for your example.

I am also using the `\s` "whitespace" character class rather than `[ ]`, as I believe it is clearer.

Testing it out:

```
$ echo "$response"
{"found":"true","downloadLink":"http:\/\/www.addic7ed.com\/updated\/1\/86593\/2"}
$ value=downloadLink
$ echo "$response" | sed -e "s/^.*\"$value\"\s*:\s*\"\([^\"]*\)\".*$/\1/"
http:\/\/www.addic7ed.com\/updated\/1\/86593\/2
$ value=found       
$ echo "$response" | sed -e "s/^.*\"$value\"\s*:\s*\"\([^\"]*\)\".*$/\1/"
true
```

By the way, if you're using bash, you can avoid `echo $var | sed` by using `<<<`:

```
sed -e "s/^.*\"$value\"\s*:\s*\"\([^\"]*\)\".*$/\1/" <<<"$response"
```

Comment: Thanks for these advices!

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not expanded inside single quotes. You could use double quotes insted like

```
sed "s/$variable/newlaue/g" ...
```

but then you should be extra careful with the contents of `$variable`, since sed will interpret any special characters in the variable (like the slash `/`) in this specific example.